# How can I use logical operators when searching for packages in Aptitude?

Tags: apt-get, aptitude

1) How to search for packages matching "word1 *or* word2" with aptitude?

2) How to search for packages matching "word1 *and* word2" with aptitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't clear to me from the documentation initially either. In my case, I wanted to search for packages that matched a name and were installed.

Anyway, the key is that *each argument* is a space separated list of conditions that are AND'd, and each argument is OR'd. So:

```
$ aptitude search "foo bar"
```

Will search for all packages that contain the string `foo` *and* the string `bar`

Where as:

```
$ aptitude search foo bar
```

Will search for all packages which contain either `foo` *or* `bar`

You can then combine this with other [conditions that aptitude accepts](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide) to do things like:

```
$ aptitude search "~i python"
```

Will list all *installed* packages that contain the string `python` in their name

There are also other ways of doing this. For example:

```
$ aptitude search "?and(foo, bar)"
$ aptitude search "?or(foo, bar)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [aptitude search pattern quick reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html).

> `pattern1 | pattern2`: Select packages that match pattern1, pattern2, or both.
>
> `pattern1 pattern2`: Select any package that matches both pattern1 and pattern2.

Since that's a pipe, make sure it's escaped or in a string if you're running `aptitude` from a shell; it has a special meaning for shells.